# Image GD Resizing Issue

Tags: php, html, image, png, gd

So I'm trying to take two large images (but later I'll be combinging 6 images in total), resize them to the x, y width, height I have taken from photoshop, and combine them into one 460 x 230 sized image.

This is the code I'm using

```
<?php

$dest = imagecreatefrompng('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/hero/ana/career-portrait.png');
$src = imagecreatefrompng('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/game/rank-icons/season-2/rank-6.png');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagealphablending($src, false);
imagesavealpha($src, true);


//imagescale($dest, 396, 161.92);
$some = imagecreate(460, 230);

$dest2 = resize($dest, 396, 162);
$src2 = resize($src, 79.19, 79.19);

//imagecopyresized($dest, $dest, 0, 0, 0, 0, 396, 161.92, 1098, 449);
imagecopyresized($src, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 79.19, 79.19, 256, 256);
//$img2 = imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 256, 256, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.
imagecopymerge($dest2, $src2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 460, 230, 50);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest, 'merged2.png');
imagepng($dest2);
//file_put_contents('merged.png', $contents);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($some);
imagedestroy($dest2);
imagedestroy($src2);
imagedestroy($img2);
//imagedestroy($then);

function resize($img, $width, $height, $stretch = false)
    {
        $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagealphablending($temp, true);
        imagesavealpha($temp, true);

        $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($temp, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Background color
        imagefill($temp, 0, 0, $bg);

        if ($stretch)
        {
            imagecopyresampled($temp, img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($img), imagesy($img));
        }
        else
        {
            if (imagesx($img) <= $width && imagesy($img) <= $height)
            {
                $fwidth = imagesx($img);
                $fheight = imagesy($img);
            }
            else
            {
                $wscale = $width / imagesx($img);
                $hscale = $height / imagesy($img);
                $scale = min($wscale, $hscale);
                $fwidth = $scale * imagesx($img);
                $fheight = $scale * imagesy($img);
            }
            imagecopyresampled($temp,
                $img,
                ($width - $fwidth) / 2, ($height - $fheight) / 2,
                0, 0,
                $fwidth, $fheight,
                imagesx($img), imagesy($img)
            );
        }
        return $temp;
    }
```

The issue is that the image rendered is very faded 
because of this line:

`imagecopymerge($dest2, $src2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 460, 230, 50);`

If I change the 50, which is the PCT value to 100, it shows one image with a black background (masking the other image), but if I change it to 0, it shows only the other image with a black background (masking the other image) 
If the value is either 0 or 100, the image shown is at its full color though. How do I merge these 2 images together while preserving their transparency and vibrancy of color?

Comment: I've also tried using  these values: `imagealphablending($dest, true);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagealphablending($src, true);
imagesavealpha($src, true);
`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `imagecopymerge` use `imagecopy`. You also always need to correctly specify the dimensions of the source image when copying:

```
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/hero/ana/career-portrait.png');
$src = imagecreatefrompng('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/game/rank-icons/season-2/rank-6.png');

$dest2 = resize($dest, 396, 162);
imagedestroy($dest);
$src2 = resize($src, 79, 79); // should be int not float.
imagedestroy($src);

// the last 2 params must match the width/height of the $src2 image.
imagecopy($dest2, $src2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79, 79);
imagedestroy($src2);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest2);

imagedestroy($dest2);
```

You don't need to change the alpha settings on `$dest` or `$src` because they aren't being rendered - you render the new image resource created in, and returned by, your `resize` function. Because of this you do need to slightly change the function:

```
function resize($img, $width, $height, $stretch = false)
{
    $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagealphablending($temp, false); // changed to false.
    imagesavealpha($temp, true);
    ...
```

---

***Edit:***

You might be better off simply using the `imagescale` function instead of using your own `resize` function:

```
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/hero/ana/career-portrait.png');
$src = imagecreatefrompng('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/game/rank-icons/season-2/rank-6.png');

$dest2 = imagescale($dest, 396);
imagealphablending($dest2, false);
imagesavealpha($dest2, true);
$src2 = imagescale($src, 79);

imagecopy($dest2, $src2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79, 79);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest2);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($dest2);
imagedestroy($src2);
```